# What is the right word for reaction but not exactly reaction

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

How would I describe that a person starts using a medical device and it had strange effects on him/her. It's kind of reaction but it's not exactly reaction because it is not all the time.

The device started or kicked off strange medical complication/behavior. What is the right word for that? Looking for formal word.

Thesaurus hasn't helped much.

Comment: Aren't those side effects of the device?

Comment: @YosefBaskin Not exactly, side effects are generally known and accepted. The things it induces are very weird. For example it can make your face numb which is a nightmare and you have to stop using the device.

Comment: @WeatherVane that suggests suitability, it's not the right word in this case. Consider the patient perfectly healthy with no issues before using this device and consider this device auxiliary, not life saving etc.

Comment: Apart from that, why don't you like **reaction**? Why do you think a reaction has to be continuous to qualify as a reaction?

Comment: It's not uncommon for people to call all reactions *allergic* reactions, which may be what you're thinking here. But it's certainly possible to have a reaction without it being due to an allery

Comment: @WeatherVane A reaction is generally deterministic, you apply a thing and you see reaction. In this case, its very weird. You wear it at night and it starts to make you feel miserable in the middle of night but during day time, it doesn't cause any issues.

Comment: @JimMack Allergic reaction is typically to material, this is not material. It's very difficult to logically connect the "reactions" it causes and it's not the material.

Comment: A **reaction** is deterministic in *physics*. Please see [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/reaction): **1.2** An adverse physiological response to a substance that has been breathed in, ingested, or touched. One example given there includes the term **adverse effect** if you prefer that to **side effect**.

Comment: The word is *still* [reaction](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reaction): "a response to some treatment, situation, or stimulus" and "bodily response to or activity aroused by a stimulus." Just because the particular reaction isn't known or anticipated in advance doesn't mean that it isn't one.

Comment: I think I will go with "caused complex medical events". Saw an article which said "Adverse clinical events reported" . Sound ok?

Comment: No it sounds like a jargon generator. "Complex medical events" is so vague it could be "covering for staff holidays". Keep it simple and specific – there was an unexpected **adverse reaction** to the treatment. The question comes across as though you have already decided, and don't really want suggestions.

Comment: @WeatherVane Not decided, thanks for feedback.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it’s not about English.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can use *adverse effect*.

> **Adverse Effect:** An adverse effect is an undesired harmful effect resulting from a medication or other intervention, such as surgery. An adverse effect may be termed a "side effect", when judged to be secondary to a main or therapeutic effect.
> [[**Wikipedia**]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adverse_effect)

Edit: Sorry just saw that @Weathervane has already written the same answer in the comment. But i think every answer in the comments are right.

Answer (score 0):

This would certainly be called a *side effect* even if it is new and yet unknown. That is where the reported side effects first come from. This would make them *unexpected* or *unwanted* side effects. You can also say that this *affected* them negatively. Otherwise a terrible *result* of the treatment.

I've tried such a cure resulting in numbness or peripheral neuropathy, and it is certainly an awful side effect.